# How to name snapshots as well as ami's in amazon date lifecycle manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have amazon datalifecycle manager setup creating EBS-Backed AMI Snapshots

Using the tagging feature I am able to have the AMI's created with the names I like, but the snapshots are blank (-), is there a way to add a tag or a setting to name these as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Copy tags from source" in the Lifecycle policy. Should copy name of the volume to the snapshot, as volume name is a 'tag'.